# Degree of an ODE [not a]

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> The degree of a differential equation, when its a polynomial equation in derivatives, is the highest power of the highest order derivative involved.

Examples

> i) $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}-\frac{dy}{dx}+xy^2=0$ The degree is 1

> ii) $(\frac{dy}{dx})^2+\frac{dy}{dx}+x\sin(y)=0$ The degree is 2

> iii) $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+\cos\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)=0$ The degree is not defined

Why is the degree of $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+\cos\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)=0$$ not defined, since it is still a polynomial in $y''$?

**Edit:**

Considering the fact that different sources provide different definitions, I look for a reliable and complete definition of what a degree is, and why it is/ isnt defined in this case

Comment: The answer is "it depends", see the discussions in the duplicate links. You will have to check for yourself what the latest definition of "degree of an ODE" in your course materials is. It could be like cited, only dependent on the highest-order derivative, or the degree could only be defined for fully polynomial or fully algebraic equations.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm really confused now.. Many textbooks I read say that its degree is undefined. Now going through the links, it doesnt seem so. Can you provide a proper answer?

Comment: So does that make my answer wrong?

Comment: @ABCD I wouldnt say its wrong. The definition is different everywhere

Comment: Please consider reopening this question

Comment: @ABCD : Your answer is perfectly fine, a somewhat authoritative definition (always also check the talk page for dissent) and the application of the given definition with its deviating demand that the equation be polynomial in all terms.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'll add the exact definition along with some examples given

Comment: Thank you, this makes your question clear, but also removes the question(?). As $\cos(y')$ is obviously not polynomial in $y'$, there is no contradiction between examples and definition. // For the second part, the degree is in general not important enough for ODE's, so that there is no general, authoritative definition, no mainstream. So any general answer will be close to an opinion.

Comment: It makes sense. You can add this as an answer. Ill accept it

Comment: The existing answer already tells this, no reason not to accept it. I did not add an answer because the linked answers already contain this discussion.

Comment: Thats kind of you :) @ABCD also deserves it of course ;)

Comment: @LutzLehmann, thank you for sharing your answers. Also thanks to Datboi for accepting my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_differential_equation#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20degree%20of,in%20all%20of%20its%20derivatives.) states the definition of degree of ODE as: the degree of a differential equation is the power of its highest derivative, after the equation has been made rational and integral in all of its derivatives.

According to you , polynomial should be formed in highest order derivative, which is not the case. The polynomial should be in **all** of it's derivatives, and hence the degree of the DE $y''+\cos(y')=0$ is not defined.