# Confusion in the definition of the degree of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Some local books in my area give definition of  degree of a ordinary differential equation as follows:

**Definition:**  The degree of a differential equation, of which the differential coefficients are free from radicals and fractions, is the positive integral index of the highest power of the highest order derivatives involved.

**My Question:** if we reduce a non-polynomial form differential  equation to required form then differential equation will change and if differential equation are not the same one then why we choose degree of other differential equation to say degree of original one ?

**Example** The  degree of differential equation $$ \sqrt {\frac{dy}{dx}+y}=x$$ is $1$ after it is free from radical and fractions $$\frac{dy}{dx}+y=x^2$$ but according to me these are not same differential equation.  Can I use the same way to find degree of following differential equations?

$1.$ $\sin(\frac{dy}{dx})=x$ by taking sin inverse .

$2.$ $e^{y’}=x$ by taking log function both sides.

$3.$ $(\frac{dy}{dx}+y)^{\frac{1}{2}}= (\frac{d^2y}{dx^2})^{\frac{1}{3}}$ by taking power $6$ both sides etc.

I am confused how to use this definition. Is this correct definition? Please clearly me . Thanks.

Comment: This is a controversial topic with no definitive answer. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3809372/115115, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3783375/115115, or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3576423/what-is-the-definition-of-the-degree-of-a-differential-equation and many others for earlier discussions of that topic.

Comment: In your example - this might not be the same equation, but "degree" is a much coarser classification than the actual equation (degree is here a function from equations to integers). Provided the definition is consistent, the fact that you transform the equation to find the degree doesn't matter. [And if you can solve the second equation, you can check which of the solutions solve the original]. The definition you are given doesn't cover transcendental functions - so $1$ and $2$ are not included. But you can try to find solutions by the method you suggest.

Comment: @MarkBennet so whenever I see transcendental function with derivatives coefficient i can say directly that degree is not defined according to above definition of degree ?

Comment: The definition does not cover transcendental functions.